# How can i open dta file with correct encoding in python?

Tags: python, dta

While opening dta file like this:

```
df = pd.read_stata('selfemp.dta')

print(data)
```

I get almost all columns with `Nan`

In this code I cannot add any encoding, as the `TypeError` arises

I need to open this file with right encoding to see all the columns correctly

Comment: What application generates this file?  Are you sure it isn't a binary format?

Comment: try to specify the encoding as param: `pd.read_stata('selfemp.dta', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: You sure its enconding, not file problem? Nan is None

Comment: Stata dta files are binary files, and text was ASCII in older versions and is UTF8 in newer ones. That is the reason why the `read_stata` function has no provision for encoding. If you see NaN, that means that data is missing in the file. That being said to correctly display text, your local application has to know about UTF8...

Comment: @MarcoParola *encoding* is not a valid keyword for the *read_stata()* function